# Liquibase: Copy column data into a new column in the same table

Tags: sql, database, liquibase

I have a table with a column A. I am creating a new column B. B will have the same data as column A. How do I replicate the column in Liquibase? Is there some expression I can write to do the replication?

Answer (score 21):

this is possible too:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="your_name">
    <addColumn tableName="your_table">
        <column name="b" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="2" author="your_name">
    <update tableName="your_table">
        <column name="b" valueComputed="a"/>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasnt looking directly for this, but the clue about `valueComputed` helped me a lot

Answer (score 16):

Create a new changeset where you add a new column, and then update column `B` using the `<sql>` tag:

```
<changeSet author="yourName" id="example">
    <addColumn catalogName="db"
               schemaName="public"
               tableName="yourTable">
        <!-- replace varchar(255) with the actual type of column A -->
        <column name="B" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </addColumn>

    <sql>UPDATE yourTable SET B = A</sql>
</changeSet>
```